# imprimir array na quantidade de valores de outro array

Tags: php, array, php-7

Eu sou novo em php e estou com o seguinte problema, eu queria fazer a impressão de um array com valores string na quantidade de valores de outro array com valores inteiros.

Isso deve ser assim.

$string = array('a','b','c');  // Essa é um array com string.
$num  = array(3,2,1);  // Essa é um array com a quantidade de impressões.

O resultado tem que ser um array assim.
['a','a','a'], ['a','a'], ['a'], ['b','b','b'], ['b','b'], ['b'], ['c','c','c'], ['c','c'], ['c']

Já tentei com for, array_slice e array_splice porém não consegui.
Alguém pode me dar um direção de como fazer isso ?

Agradeço a todos que puder dar uma ajuda.

Comment: Isso está com cara de exercício de curso. Já tentou usar um for, foreach? É uma solução. Tente com uma dessas formas que citei e posta (edita o post) aqui que tento te direcionar.
"A partir do PHP 5.4 você também pode utilizar a sintaxe contraída de array, que troca array() por [] " Veja em https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Comment: Complementando, dá uma olhada no array_fill também

Comment: Obrigado colega pela direção. Ah! e também não é exercício de curso não, é um script que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Ao solucionar posta aqui caso fizer diferente do modo que o Euclides fez pra você. Caso tiver posto uma solução também pra enriquecer o conteúdo do post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma Função no PHP que pode ajudar. [Referência array_fill](http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/manual/pt_BR/function.array-fill.php)

```
array_fill ( int $start_index , int $num , mixed $value ).
```

E você pode fazer um simples foreach com os dois array. De forma que o valor a ser replicado, será o do array $string, e o número de vezes do $num. Assim, como vc mesmo definiu.

```
$string = ['a','b','c'];
$num = [3,2,1];

$newArray = [];

foreach($string as $s){
   foreach($num as $n){
      $newArray[] = array_fill(0,$n,$s);   
   }
}
```

Para visualizar, pode usar var_dump(). Ou para ficar mais visual, faça mais dois foreach para visualizar o array multidimensional que foi criado.

Assim,

```
foreach($newArray as $n){
   foreach($n as $value){
     echo $value;
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado companheiro, eu vou olhar essa função indicada do php.